# How to calculate the HHG (Heller Heller Gorfine) correlation

Tags: statistics, permutations, correlation, hypothesis-testing

HHG (A consistent multivariate test of association based on ranks of distances) is introduced in:

Heller, R., Heller, Y., & Gorfine, M. (2012b). A consistent multivariate test of association based on ranks of distances. Biometrika, arXiv preprint arXiv:1201.3522.

Newer version available here: [HHG](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Malka_Gorfine/publication/51989966_A_consistent_multivariate_test_of_association_based_on_ranks_of_distances/file/3deec523239a82b1f6.pdf?origin=publication_detail).

Assuming I can calculate test statistics T(X,Y), where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times p}$, $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times q}$ how do I transform it to [0,1] ?

I suppose $N_{sim}$ simulations are required to get $T_i(X,Y_{perm,i})$, where $Y_{perm,i}$ is Y with randomly permuted rows (?) and $i \in \{1,N_{sim}\}$, to calculate the correlation (maybe association is a batter term?) ($\in$[0,1]) and p-value?
I calculate p as the (number of $T_i>T$)/$N_{sim}$, is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The method described at the end of the question above (of calculating Nsim permutations) is indeed the standard way of calculating a p_value for a permutation test such as ours. In fact our R package calculates the p_value this way, so you dont need the perform the permutations yourself. In order to get the p_values please set the parameters as follows:
is.sequential = F
nr.perm = Nsim

We output four p_values of four variants of the score. The p_value for the most popular statistic can be found in perm.pval.hhg.sl.
For more information on the package, please see the manual at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HHG/HHG.pdf.
Note, that this number is a p_value and does not have any other meaning as a correlation measure

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)